# Network flow chart

Tags: powerbi, flowchart

I work with supply chain networks and I'd like to represent/visualize the flow of products through the network. I'm using Power BI.
Each pair of origin/destination can have more than one link. This link represents a particular transportation mode or a particular group of products.
Besides categories, there are fields that represents numerical values like the flow through the link, or a flow constrain through the link.
These values may be used as weights at the charts.
So far, all Power BI visual that I tested only represents one link per origin/destination pair.

- Force-Directed Graph shown more than one, but it superposes the links.
- Network Navigator has a similar approach but only shows one link per origin/destination.

Is there a Power BI visual capable of represent a flow through a network with "great circle" kind of links between nodes and do not superposes them?

The following table is an example of the data I'd like to visualize:

| Link_ID | Link_NN | Origin_ID | Dest_ID | Link_TP | Product_TP | Min_Vol | Max_Vol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Pipe_A | LOC_1 | LOC_2 | Pipe | Diesel | 0 | 1000 |
| ABD | Pipe_B | LOC_1 | LOC_2 | Pipe | Gasoline | 0 | 2000 |
| ABE | Truck_A | LOC_1 | LOC_2 | Truck | Diesel | 0 | 100 |
| ABF | Ship_A | LOC_1 | LOC_3 | Ship | Fuel Oil | 0 | 10000 |

Link_TP and Product_TP would be used in slicers. The main point is to visualize all the links that exists between an origin/destination set.

Comment: Can you show me mini dataset with picture? How exactly you establish relation between the models? I must see for answer.

Comment: In general terms, the table contains the following columns:
Link_ID | Link_Name | Origin_ID | Destination_ID | Link_Type | Product_Type | Min_Vol | Max_Vol
Origin_ID and Destination_ID are stored at other table, but I can manipulate that with DAX, for instance. The idea is to use Link_ID/Link_Name as a class, so even a pair Origin/Destination have more than one link, all of them are shown, instead of just one "line" between them.
We can think like a flight map, where airports may be connected by many airlines, each of them represented by a "line/arc" between the airports.

Answer (score 0):

I work for a commercial graph drawing library provider and I can tell you that we have been getting similar requests a few times, already. Thus I believe there is no such good visual available out-of-the box.

However Power BI can be extended easily and we have had customers doing exactly that: Building a custom Power BI visual with our third party diagramming control to add the missing features to their dashboards.

To give you some ideas, here are visualizations that sound similar to what you are looking for.

[Interactive Process Mining Diagram](https://live.yworks.com/demos/complete/processmining/index.html) Online Demo

[Sankey Flow Diagram](https://live.yworks.com/demos/layout/sankey/index.html) Online Demo

[Network Flow visualization](https://live.yworks.com/demos/analysis/networkflows/index.html) Online Demo

Also there is a GitHub repo that shows how to create a custom Power BI visual with the above technology:

https://github.com/yWorks/graphs-in-power-bi

<sup>As mentioned: DISCLAIMER: I work for the company that creates that library, however I do not represent my company on SO. My statements and thoughts on SO are my own.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

PowerBI, no.

And, in general, I do not see any library to provide exactly this.  The closest is probably deck.gl's ArcLayer.  I think ArcLayer is flashy and all but it's not as clear as I want.

There is an excellent academic paper on the subject that describes exactly what I want.

"Force-directed layout of origin-destination flow maps" 2017 by Jenny et. al.